# the apache tomcat service ended unexpectedly

Tags: tomcat, windows-services

We have a Tomcat server crash problem in production.
We did not find the error traces in tomcat logs or application.
We just have the message of the Windows Event Viewer:

> The Apache Tomcat service ended unexpectedly for the first time

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a core dump file anywhere, it depends on how the application was started. First, look in windows\system32 directory if anything was dumped there.

Comment: Thanks. I will ask production team to verify.